# Can I send a custom event from a eventBus listener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following on a Vue component:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      quotes: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    eventBus.$on("quoteWasAdded", message => {
      this.quotes.push(message);
      this.$emit("quotesWereUpdated", this.quotes);
    });
  }
```

What I want to achieve is when the quotes arrays is updated, it creates a custom event so I can use it on a parent or on other siblings.

I'm trying to use it on the parent component, but it's returning undefined

Parent:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <p>{{messages.length}}</p>
    <quote-header></quote-header>
    <new-quote></new-quote>
    <quotes @quotesWereUpdated="messages = $event"></quotes>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: How do you know it's *'returning undefined'*?

Comment: because it's returning an error saying that is not possible to return the length of an undefined object

Comment: What is the initial value of `messages`? Is there anything else that changes it? I don't think the event is to blame here. Try replacing it with `@quotesWereUpdated="log(messages = $event)"` and add `log (x) {console.log(x)}` to your methods. That should allow you to spy on the value of `$event` that's being assigned to `messages`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
<quotes @quotesWereUpdated="updateMessages"></quotes>
```

then declare a method:

```
    updateMessages (data) {
      this.messages = data
    }
```